# pandas - how to get last n groups of a groupby object and combine them as a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

How to get last 'n' groups after `df.groupby()` and combine them as a dataframe.

```
data = pd.read_sql_query(sql=sqlstr, con=sql_conn, index_col='SampleTime')
grouped = data.groupby(data.index.date,sort=False)
```

After doing `grouped.ngroups` i am getting total number of groups 277. I want to combine last 12 groups and generate a dataframe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pandas `GroupBy` objects are iterables. To extract the last *n* elements of an iterable, there's generally no need to create a list from the iterable and slice the last *n* elements. This will be memory-expensive.

Instead, you can use either `itertools.islice` (as suggested by @mtraceur) or `collections.deque`. Both work in O(*n*) time.

#### [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

Unlike a generator, a Pandas `GroupBy` object is an iterable which can be reused. Therefore, you can calculate the number of groups via `len(g)` for a `GroupBy` object `g` and then slice `g` via `islice`. Or, perhaps  more idiomatic, you can use `GroupBy.ngroups`. Then use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate an iterable of dataframes:

```
from operator import itemgetter

g = data.groupby(data.index.date, sort=False)
res = pd.concat(islice(map(itemgetter(1), g), max(0, g.ngroups-12), None))
```

#### [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

Alternatively, you can use `collections.deque` and specify `maxlen`, then concatenate as before.

```
from collections import deque

grouped = data.groupby(data.index.date, sort=False)
res = pd.concat(deque(map(itemgetter(1), grouped), maxlen=12))
```

As described in the `collections` docs:

> Once a bounded length `deque` is full, when new items are added, a
>   corresponding number of items are discarded from the opposite end....
>   They are also useful for tracking transactions and other pools of data
>   where only the most recent activity is of interest.

Comment: in your example where can it be seen that you recover the last 5?

Comment: Great catch using deques, but you are still iterating over all groups. So the advantage is to save memory in this case, am I right? Good catch anyway

Comment: @RafaelC, Yes, the advantage is principally lower memory usage. You can't avoid iterating over all groups.

Comment: @Yuca, `maxlen=12` here.

Comment: I'm curious, did you also consider/evaluate doing `itertools.islice(map(...), len(grouped) - 12, len(grouped)` instead of a `collections.deque(map(...), maxlen=12)`? My intuition is to prefer `islice` in this case, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @mtraceur, I've gone ahead and added the `islice` solution (but using `ngroups`), hope that's ok.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know the order of `grouped`

```
grouped = zip(*df.groupby(data.index.date,sort=False))
pd.concat(list(grouped)[1][-12:])
```

Answer (score 1):

use `pd.concat` on lists comprehension and `groupby.get_group`

```
pd.concat([grouped.get_group(x) for x in list(grouped.groups.keys())[-12:]])
```

Comment: I just tried this on a dataframe I was working on, and this seemed to be what OP asked for? `ed:` the concat didn't work, but `.tail(12)` returned the final 12 groups

Comment: new version should be aligned to what OP wants :) (although it doesn't provide much vs rahlf23's version)

Comment: @MathewSavage that is really interesting, doc says it return the last rows from each group, not the last groups. Maybe I should test it too

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a list comprehension to `pd.concat()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
['A',1,2],
['A',7,6],
['B',1,3],
['B',9,9],
['C',1,8],
['A',4,3],
['C',7,6],
['D',4,2]],
columns=['Var','Val1','Val2'])

last_n = 2
grouped = df.groupby('Var')

pd.concat([grouped.get_group(group) for i, group in enumerate(grouped.groups) if i>=len(grouped)-last_n])
```

Yields:

```
  Var  Val1  Val2
4   C     1     8
6   C     7     6
7   D     4     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Get last n keys and filter dataframe with those keys

```
n = 12
grouped = data.groupby(data.index.date)
keys = list(grouped.groups.keys())
last_n_groups = data.loc[data[data.index.date].isin(keys[-n:])]
```